# Build a library, with undefined Macro

Tags: c++

If I have two projects and one library. The library requires a defined macro, so

```
/* mylib.cpp */
int stack[STACK_SIZE];
```

In Project 1, the Stack Size needs to be defined as:

```
/* project_1_main.cpp */
#define STACK_SIZE 50
```

For Project 2 the stack size needs to be different

```
/* project_2_main.cpp */
#define STACK_SIZE 800
```

Is there a way to build a library with an undefined macro and leave it for the project to define?

I am using GCC compiler, C++03, but I am not allowed to turn the library into a template.

EDIT:  With your input, I decided that I will not pre compile the library, use the directory as as included source files, then add -D STACK_SIZE=50 option to compile with corresponding size to each project.  Longer clean builds, but it is DRY.

Comment: Glad you caught the `now/not` issue as well as the title `:p`

Comment: Could you define `STACK_SIZE` as something that would make the compiler pop, such as a character, then require each project to issue `-D STACK_SIZE=50` and `-D STACK_SIZE=800` on the build line?

Comment: @jnbbender No, you couldn't. That would just make the library fail to compile.

Comment: Change both libraries, throw them into garbage, or wrap both library headers with each macro defined accordingly.

Comment: macros are simple text replacements so no, it is not possible to later define them since the preprocessor runs before the compilation and needs to do the replacements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Macros used in source files that are part of a library must be defined *when the library is compiled*; redefining the macros later on in another source file will not change the library's behavior.

If you need the library's behavior to be modifiable, you will most likely need to allocate this array dynamically based on a value passed to a function in the library, e.g.

```
int *stack = NULL;
size_t stack_size = 0;

void mylib_init_stack(size_t size) {
    if (stack == NULL) {
        stack = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        stack_size = size;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "mylib ERROR: stack already initialized\n");
    }
}
```

and call that function to initialize the library when starting up your applications.

Answer (score 2):

> *"Is there a way to build a library with an undefined macro and leave it for the project to define?"*

You can use a template parameter, and a small wrapper class used in the dependent projects instead of that macro:

`stack.hpp`:

```
 template<size_t StackSize>
 struct stack_impl {
     static std::array<int,StackSize> stack;
 };

 template <size_t StackSize>
 std::array<int,StackSize> stack_impl<StackSize>::stack;
```

The dependent projects use it like

`project_1_main.cpp`:

```
 #include "stack.hpp"
 typedef stack_impl<50> Project1Stack;
```

`project_2_main.cpp`:

```
 #include "stack.hpp"
 typedef stack_impl<800> Project2Stack;
```

access

```
 Project1Stack::stack[5] = 6;


 std::cout << Project2Stack::stack[42] << std::endl;
```

---

Anyway, you may want to have generic function implementations (independent of the actual project settings) operating with specific size specified for `int` arrays passed. So you may create simple wrappers for an API that operates on a pointer and size:

```
 class stack_base {
     int* stack_start_;
     const size_t size_;
 protected:
     stack_base(int* stack_start, const size_t size)
     : stack_start_(stack_start), size_(size) {}
 public: 
     // Provide public interface to operate on stack
     void push(int);
     int pop();
 };

 template<size_t Size>
 class stack : public stack_base {
     std::array<int,Size> stack_mem;

 public:
     stack() 
     : stack_base(&stack_mem[0],stack_mem.size()) {
     }
 };
```